# how to get datetime value from my database to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**My Model**

```
namespace Maintenance_.Models
{
    public class ResolutionModel
    {
         public DateTime jobStart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Resolution()
{ 
    ActivityDetailsFacade _oActivityDetailsFacade = new ActivityDetailsFacade();
    ResolutionFacade _oResolutionFacade = new ResolutionFacade();
    DataTable act = _oActivityDetailsFacade.getActivityDetails("00704 - 4.29.2014", _oAppSetting.ConnectionString);
    foreach( DataRow temp in act.Rows)
    {
        _oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart = Datetime.????;        <====
    }
return View();
}
```

I have a jobStart field in my database, and its a datetime type. Now I want my jobStart value from my database to be transfer in my model: **_oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart**. How should I pass it??

Comment: what is the name of column in db?

Comment: Field: **JobStart** type: datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have noticed you using an iteration in the `foreach` loop so each time you will assign the value to your model, the previous datetime will be erased. But you must have something like this:

```
_oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart =(DateTime)temp["JobStart"];
```

But remember that if you want to store all the rows if there are many you need some changes.

Comment: why this not worked for OP: ``temp["JobStart"] as DateTime`` ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **Column** Name is `JobStart`:

```
_oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart = temp["JobStart"] as DateTime;
```

in your loop:

```
foreach( DataRow temp in act.Rows)
    {
        _oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart = temp["JobStart"] as DateTime;  <====
    }
```

Comment: Ehsan, the code didn't work sorry, I use the other one: _oResolutionModelMODEL.jobStart =(DateTime)temp["JobStart"]; this works.